# Triggering a click event on dynamically created ID (with ID based on parent element)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm a bit stumped as to why the following is not working.

Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/henzen/3qtd40ne/1/).

The HTML is dynamically created, resulting in something like this:

```
<div id="manageStatuses">
   <div id="statusRowID_1" class="row">row 1
       <div id="statusRowBtn_1"></div>
   </div>
   <div id="statusRowID_2" class="row">row 2
       <div id="statusRowBtn_2"></div>
   </div>
   <div id="statusRowID_3" class="row">row 3
       <div id="statusRowBtn_3"></div>
   </div>
</div>
<!-- ... etc -->
```

jQuery/Javascript to handle the user clicking on the row.  When they do, I'd like to trigger a click on the corresponding child div.

```
// user clicked on a status row
$('#manageStatuses').on("click", '[id^="statusRowID_"]', function () {
    var id = $(this).attr('id').split('_')[1];
    alert(`${id} row clicked`);
    // triggerHandler() instead of trigger() else it will recursively bubble up the DOM
    $(`#manageStatuses #statusRowBtn_${id}`).triggerHandler("click");
});

// handle dynamically triggered click on status child div.  This code is not reached.
$('#manageStatuses').on("click", '[id^="statusRowBtn_"]', function () {
    var id = $(this).attr('id').split('_')[1];
    alert(`${id} child dynamically clicked`);
    // do other things based on ID...
});
```

Everything works except the `triggerHandler()` call (I think).

I'd appreciate any pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `trigger()` and stop the event propagation using `stopPropagation()`.

```js
// user clicked on a status row
$('#manageStatuses').on("click", '[id^="statusRowID_"]', function () {
    var id = $(this).attr('id').split('_')[1];
    alert(`${id} row clicked`);
    // triggerHandler() instead of trigger() else it will recursively bubble up the DOM
    $(`#manageStatuses #statusRowBtn_${id}`).trigger("click");
});

// handle dynamically triggered click on status row.  This code is not reached.
$('#manageStatuses').on("click", '[id^="statusRowBtn_"]', function (e) {
    var id = $(this).attr('id').split('_')[1];
    alert(`${id} child dynamically clicked`);
    e.stopPropagation();
    // do other things based on ID...
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="manageStatuses">
   <div id="statusRowID_1" class="row">row 1
       <div id="statusRowBtn_1"></div>
   </div>
   <div id="statusRowID_2" class="row">row 2
       <div id="statusRowBtn_2"></div>
   </div>
   <div id="statusRowID_3" class="row">row 3
       <div id="statusRowBtn_3"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Damn!  That works, thanks Mamun.  But why doesn't the original code work with triggerHandler()?  I thought that was the whole point...